# Unable to store/retrieve an object using chrome.storage.sync in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects

I am trying to store a [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) object, created from the text that user has selected, using `chrome.storage.sync` with the page URL as the key. Since, there can be multiple selections associated with a particular page, I am using an array to hold all the `Range` objects.

But I am unable to do it successfully. Each time I try to push a new `Range` object to the array, the previous objects become empty. Hence, I only get an array in which all objects are empty except for the last `Range` object that I pushed.

This is my code snippet:

```
var selectedRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0); 
var key = request.url;
chrome.storage.sync.get([key], function(result){
    /*check if an object is already present in storage with this key*/
    if(Object.keys(result).length === 0 && result.constructor === Object){
        console.log("No entry for " + key + " present in storage");

        var entry = {}; 
        /*create a new array with the first Range object*/
        entry[key] = [selectedRange];
        chrome.storage.sync.set(entry, function(){
            console.log(entry);
        }); 
    } else {
        console.log("Entry found!");

        var value = result[key];
        /*push the Range object in the existing array*/ 
        value.push(selectedRange);

        chrome.storage.sync.remove(key, function(response){
            var entry = {}; 
            entry[key] = value;
            chrome.storage.sync.set(entry, function(){
                console.log(entry);
            }); 
        }); 
    }
});
```

Here's the output from my console when I add 3 objects one after the other:

[image: output from the console when I add Range objects]

What's even more weird is that if I simply try to store a string instead of the Range object, say, by using this definition for `selectedRange`,

```
var selectedRange = "SomeString";
```

the storing works exactly as expected. The [documentation for storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) says that it can store user data as objects.

---

**EDIT**:

With the help of @wOxxOm , I have been able to locate the problem to the fact that `chrome.storage` api can only store JSONifiable objects but `Range` object is not JSONifiable.

I thought about creating a new object and storing just the `startContainer`, `startOffset`, `endContainer` and the `endOffset` properties. Then, I would've been able to recreate the `Range` object using the `range.setStart(startNode, startOffset)` and `range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset)` methods.

But then I found that even the `Node` objects are not JSONifiable! :(

It would be great if you could tell me a fix around this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: As you can see in the documentation only JSON-ifiable objects are stored. To preview the result you can run JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourObject)).

Comment: I added this statement: 
`selectedRange = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectedRange));` 
and tried it again but now its only empty objects, even the last pushed object is empty now.

Comment: I think the problem is with `JSON.stringify(selectedRange)`. I don't think its working. I tried `console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedRange))` and it just prints an empty object. What do you think @wOxxOm ?

Comment: It simply means that `Range` is not JSON-ifiable so you can't save it in chrome.storage.

Comment: Umm.. can you suggest something to work around that?

Comment: There's no workaround. You'll need to think of another approach. Like maybe save the index of Range elements inside document.getElementsByTagName('*') array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173741/discussion-between-nityesh-agarwal-and-woxxom).